# Overriding Ext.form.field.Hidden failed

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to override the `Ext.form.field.Hidden` with below code

```
  Ext.override('Ext.form.field.Hidden', {
      setValue: function(val) {
          this.callParent(['In override']);
          return this;
      }
  });
```

getting the below error.

```
ext-all.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$className' of undefined
    at Object.override (ext-all.js:15)
    at UserForm.js?_dc=1497267375330:10
```

I'm declared `Ext.form.field.Hidden` as an xtype in panel and want to override the setValue to handle arrays. So I'm trying to override the setValue method. But it just failed by overriding with beginning.
    Please let me know if you need any details ?

Comment: are you using `modern` toolkit?

Comment: I'm using Ext JS 4 version.

Comment: How you want to use array for hidden overriding ? Can you explain properly in question .If possible plz give some demo fiddle

Comment: Does it work if you go the Ext.define way of overriding the field instead?
i.e.:
`Ext.define('Overrides.form.field.Hidden', {

    override: 'Ext.form.field.Hidden',

    setValue: function(val) {

        this.callParent(['In override']);

        return this;

    }

});`


Sorry for bad formatting, there are no linebreaks inside comments.